# python Class from two sources

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, class, sqlalchemy

I am trying to sync data between our accounting software and our internal software.
The accounting software runs on `MSSQL` and our software runs on `PGSQL`

Is it possible to create a single class with two sources of data and possibly two different structure and a mapping method inside? or is it easier to create two distinct class with a mapping method?

One class:

```
class test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    def __init__(self, type='MSSQL'):
        self.type = type
        self.__tablename__ = __tablename__

    @classmethod
    def DBMSSQL(cls):
        return cls('MSSQL')

    @classmethod
    def DBPGSQL(cls):
        return cls('PGSQL')
```

How to map fields between the two type and how to change the engine used?

Or with two classes:

```
class testMSSQL(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "dbo"}

    to_testPGSQL():
        pass

class testPGSQL(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'testPG'

    to_testMSSQL():
        pass
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no answer to this question, it is naturally a matter of taste. What do you find easier?

Comment: What's with the dunder variables?

Comment: For me it is easier with two distinct class but I dunno if it's possible with only one without going mad.

Comment: @timgeb If you're referring to `__tablename__` and such, [they're for SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping)